# How to determine from a different folder (outside wordpress) if a visitor is logged into Wordpress

Tags: php, outside-wordpress

The WordPress area of my site (which has registration) is in for example `mydomain.com/members/`

I would like to know from a PHP routine in my `public_html` root `mydomain.com/offers.php` if they are logged into the WordPress area `mydomain.com/members`

I have tried various things to try and get this to work without success. `get_current_user_id()` always returns `0` or `is_user_logged_in()` returns `false`.

If it helps to give me the correct solution, my WordPress uses the theme MH-Magazine, and uses the plugins Paid Memberships Pro and Theme My Login.

Answer (score 1):

To use all the WordPress functions in any non- WordPress pages, you can use

```
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
Include_once('wp-load.php');
```

Then, is_user_logged_in() will work, and user cookie, session and id could be retrieve.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); 
Include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/members/wp-load.php');
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {echo ' You are currently logged in.'. '<br />';}
else
{    echo ' You are currently not logged in.'. '<br />';}
?>
```

The above code returns You are currently not logged in.
The above code when executed from the SAME folder that wordpress is in does work. 
My requirement is to execute code from a DIFFERENT folder to where wordpress resides.